# Is `finally` block executed in case there is `return` inside a `try` or a `catch` block?

Tags: scala, exception

Using a try-catch-finally construction to retrieve a database record, it seems that I need to return a value inside a `try` block in case everything was fine (as in case of an exception the end of the function is not meant to be reached). But If I return inside `try`, is `finally` code going to be reached (to close the connection etc.)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes,

The result of the `try/catch` expression will be the last line of either the `try` or `catch` block, but the `finally` block will always execute no matter what

Comment: Even if there is explicit `return` statement in the `try` block?

Comment: The only case where the `finally` block isn't executed is when `sys.exit()` is called within the `try` or the `catch` block.

Comment: Also if the JVM crashes before the finally, as I found the hard way.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

The point of a `finally` is to ensure that some cleanup code is executed no matter what path the code uses to leave the `try` block. It happens on ordinary return, when an exception is thrown and caught, and when an exception is thrown that isn't caught by this `try` block. The only thing that will prevent it running is if the program is unable to leave the `try` block at all; an infinite loop inside it, or the process being killed by some means that prevents this normal processing from happening, or something of that order. I'm pretty sure even if you exit the process from inside the `try` block that the `finally` block will be executed before the process actually dies.